# Jenkins Pipeline failing WorkflowScript: 37: expecting '}'

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have written a Jenkins Pipeline but it's failing on the following step:-

```
script {
    attachments="<a href='https://xxxxx.xxxxx.net/wiki/pages/viewpageattachments.action?pageId=${idValue}'>ATTACHMENTS</a>"

    echo '=========================URL===================' + attachments
    echo '{"id":"'${idValue}'","type":"page","title":"'${releaseVersion}'","space":{"key":"~xxxxxx"},"body":{"storage":{"value":"'${attachments}'","representation":"storage"}},"version":{"number":"2"}}' > update1.json
    //content = sh(script: "curl -u 'xxxxxxx@xxxxxx.xxx:xxxxxxxx' -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '@update1.json' https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx/wiki/rest/api/content/${idValue}", returnStdout: true)
    //rm update1.json
}
```

It gives the following error

```
WorkflowScript: 37: expecting '}', found '","representation":"storage"}},"version":{"number":"2"}}' @ line 37, column 164.
2021-11-02 18:40:23.964     age":{"value":"'${attachments}'","repres
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
def my_json = """
{
  "id":"${idValue}",
  "type":"page",
  "title":"${releaseVersion}",
  "space": {
    "key":"~xxxxxx"
  },
  "body":{
    "storage":{
      "value":"${attachments}",
      "representation":"storage"
    }
  },
  "version":{
    "number":"2"
  }
}
"""
echo "${my_json}" > update1.json
```